# How to pass python function argument to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to execute Jupyter Notebook cell through Javascript code in .py file. The test function works fine for integers. But if i pass a string as argument, the function failed. Why **integer** is working but not **string**. what should i do to make the string working. Should i have to use **document.getElementById('num').value**  Could you please help me to fix this.

js_test.py file:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML, Javascript
def check_arg(num):
    js_code = """
       var num = {0};
       console.log(num)
    """.format(num)
    display(Javascript(js_code))
```

Jupyter Notebook cell:

```
import js_test
js_test.check_arg(5)
js_test.check_arg('hi')
```

Jupyter Output:

```
Javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: hi is not defined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

Chrome Developer Console:

```
5
outputarea.js:765 ReferenceError: hi is not defined
    at eval (eval at append_javascript (outputarea.js:763), <anonymous>:2:18)
```

Comment: You need to quote `{0}`, at least if it is a string: `js_code = """var num = '{0}'; console.log(num)""".format(num)`

Comment: Thank You @Maurice. Its working for string.

Comment: for string you may have to add it with quote `" "` inside `' '` - `js_test.check_arg( '"hi"' )` or with `' '` inside `" "` - `js_test.check_arg( "'hi'" )`